# java.lang.ClassCastException in objectoutputstream readobject

Tags: java, sockets

This is the code that i used on client socket

```
Socket connected = Server.accept();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(connected.getOutputStream());

oos.writeObject(dPFPSample.serialize());
```

This the code that i used on server socket

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 5002);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

DPFPSample dpfpSample = (DPFPSample) ois.readObject();
```

i got an error `java.lang.ClassCastException exception on ois.readObject() line`

Comment: what is `dPFPSample.serialize()` doing?

Comment: Can we have the full stacktrace please?

Comment: Don't paraphrase exception stack traces - show us the actual trace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would assume that your `DPFPSamle.serialize()` returns something different then `DPFPSamle`. I'd say you don't need to call any serialization method. The stream will handle it. So just call `writeObject(dPFPSample)`

In order for this to work your class (the one you are trying to send - i.e. `DPFPSample`) must implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface.

Comment: sorry for this stupid question as its return array of byte DPFPSamle.serialize() but if i remove that i got an exception java.io.NotSerializableException

Comment: @chetan - then make your class implement java.io.Serializable

Comment: If i am not wrong you are talking about my client and server socket class.Yes I have implement Serializable

Comment: The `public class DPFPSamle implements Serializable`

Comment: This is our product API so we can't change it.We have only class file of DPFPSamle class.Is there any other solution ?

Comment: @chetan - what does the `serialize()` method return? What's its documentation.

Comment: If you are talking about DPFPSamle class then its return an array of bytes.

Comment: sory, but I can't understand your question

Comment: how is that byte array obtained. What does it represent? You must know that (it should be documented), if you are to deserialize it. Btw, is there a `deserialize(bytes)` method?

Comment: Thank you for your support I got the solution for this problem.